# Why do i get an error when using render() method in react jest testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Im trying to create a test for my component this is what i got so far

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Characters from '../../pages/charaters/characters';

import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

describe('<Characters/>', () => {
  const handleSearchByName = jest.fn();

  test("Renders <Characters/>", () => {
   render(<Characters/>);
  });

});
```

but i get the error in the render method render();

""Characters" refers to a value, but is used here as a type. Did you mean "typeof Characters"?"

Comment: Your file have to be `tsx` or `jsx`

Comment: my test file? my component file is already a tsx file

Comment: Your test file, because you are trying to use jsx syntax